# glmmadmb error: maximum number of dependent variables of 200 exceeded

Tags: r

I needed to fit a model that had about 500 fixed effects.

```
nb.xx.ff <-glmmadmb(count~Pint-1, 
                    data=dnoNM,
                    family="nbinom")
```

And was given the following error:

```
## maximum number of depdendent variables of 200 exceeded 
## use gradient_structure::set_NUM_DEPENDENT_VARIABLES(int i);
## to increase the number of dependent variables
## Error in glmmadmb(count ~ Pint - 1, data = dnoNM, family = "nbinom", zeroInflation = TRUE,  : 
##   The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)
## changed working directory to /spin1/users/swihartbj/projects/_SMFA/Pxs_2015_ctrls_only/Rnw/Final/_ilmn5 
## removed temp directory /scratch/Rtmp/Rtmp4iDtvH/glmmADMB2384f4030d4a1
```

Is there a way to increase this from the `R` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Add "-ndv 3000" to `extra.args`, as recommended [here](http://skryb.info/m/users%40admb-project.org/4CBC900B.2030906%40otter-rsch.com).  As long as the number of fixed effects is the only issue and the number (3000 in this example) listed is bigger than the number of fixed effects, this should work:

```
nb.xx.ff <-glmmadmb(count~Pint-1, 
                    data=dnoNM,
                    family="nbinom",
                    extra.args="-ndv 3000")
```